# what is superimposability of mirror images of this molecule?

Tags: stereochemistry

I don't get why (a) and (d) are achiral when we cant superimpose their respective mirror images?Or can we superimpose them?[image]

Comment: Why, we surely can.

Comment: how exactly can we do that? i am unable to.

Comment: These are like easiest examples among these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you put the mirror, in the case of a a horizontal mirror is required, or rotate the molecules 90 degrees before using a mirror to the left.

For d it is best if you rotate the C-C bond between the six memebered ring and the amide group before turning the molecule 60 degrees clockwise, then hold it beside the imaginary mirror to the left of it.